# Patch LESS file with CSS changes

Tags: css, compilation, merge, less

My team made the classic mistake wherein a new addition to the team made changes to the css directly instead of the less file we were using. No changes have been made to the less file in the meanwhile. Everything is under git as specific commits.

What's the most efficient way to merge the changes to the css into the less? There's very little use of mixins in the less, its mostly just importing bootstrap and then nesting selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps someone else will come up with a better (and more creative) answer, but my thought is the "most efficient" way is the most painful, time consuming: isolate the changes that were done to the CSS, then code them into the LESS--manually (copy/paste anyway).

That, of course, is what I am assuming you want to avoid by asking this question. I just don't see any way to avoid it.

Comment: Actually now its seems pretty obvious, should be straightforward to generate patches using git from the css file, and manually copy the added lines to the less file.